# Sending an email in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http, email, nopcommerce

I have a method that returns a list of products from the database that I would like to send to a certain email address. The method I would like to send returns a list of items. There's a `ContactUs` formula that sends a message but from costumer to store owner that I'm considering using as a base. However the data I want to send as an email are only supposed to be sent to the storeowner email address without a sender.

I want to send the list of products that is returned from this method:

```
public IList<BestsellersReportLine> DailyBestsellersReport()
{
    OrderStatus os; 
    PaymentStatus? ps = null; 
    ShippingStatus ss;
    int billingCountryId = 0;
    int recordsToReturn = 999; 
    int orderBy = 1;
    int groupBy = 1;

    int? paymentStatusId = null;
    if (ps.HasValue)
        paymentStatusId = (int)ps.Value;

    // Specifies the time range for sold products/day
    var range = new
    {
        startTimeUtc = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1),
                     endTimeUtc = DateTime.Today.AddSeconds(-1),
                     CreatedOnUtc = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1),
    };

    var query1 = from opv in _opvRepository.Table
        join o in _orderRepository.Table on opv.OrderId equals o.Id
        join pv in _productVariantRepository.Table on opv.ProductVariantId equals pv.Id
        join p in _productRepository.Table on pv.ProductId equals p.Id
        where (o.CreatedOnUtc >= range.startTimeUtc && o.CreatedOnUtc <= range.endTimeUtc) &&
        (!paymentStatusId.HasValue || paymentStatusId == o.PaymentStatusId)
        select opv;

    var query2 = groupBy == 1 ?
        //group by product variants
        from opv in query1
        group opv by opv.ProductVariantId into g
        select new
        {
            EntityId = g.Key,
                     TotalAmount = g.Sum(x => x.PriceExclTax),
                     TotalQuantity = g.Sum(x => x.Quantity),
        }
    :
        //group by products
        from opv in query1
        group opv by opv.ProductVariant.ProductId into g
        select new
        {
            EntityId = g.Key,
                     TotalAmount = g.Sum(x => x.PriceExclTax),
                     TotalQuantity = g.Sum(x => x.Quantity),
        }
    ;

    switch (orderBy)
    {
        case 1:
            {
                query2 = query2.OrderByDescending(x => x.TotalQuantity);
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            {
                query2 = query2.OrderByDescending(x => x.TotalAmount);
            }
            break;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException("Wrong orderBy parameter", "orderBy");
    }

    if (recordsToReturn != 0 && recordsToReturn != int.MaxValue)
        query2 = query2.Take(recordsToReturn);

    var result = query2.ToList().Select(x =>
            {
            var reportLine = new BestsellersReportLine()
            {
            EntityId = x.EntityId,
            TotalAmount = x.TotalAmount,
            TotalQuantity = x.TotalQuantity
            };
            return reportLine;


            }).ToList();

    //return result;
    return result.OrderBy(opv => opv.TotalQuantity).ToList();
}
```

As an email into this method:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("ContactUs")]
[CaptchaValidator]
public ActionResult ContactUsSend(ContactUsModel model, bool captchaValid)
{
    //validate CAPTCHA
    if (_captchaSettings.Enabled && _captchaSettings.ShowOnContactUsPage && !captchaValid)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", _localizationService.GetResource("Common.WrongCaptcha"));
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        string email = model.Email.Trim();
        string fullName = model.FullName;
        string subject = string.Format(_localizationService.GetResource("ContactUs.EmailSubject"), _storeInformationSettings.StoreName);

        var emailAccount = _emailAccountService.GetEmailAccountById(_emailAccountSettings.DefaultEmailAccountId);
        if (emailAccount == null)
            emailAccount = _emailAccountService.GetAllEmailAccounts().FirstOrDefault();

        string from = null;
        string fromName = null;
        string body = Core.Html.HtmlHelper.FormatText(model.Enquiry, false, true, false, false, false, false);
        //required for some SMTP servers
        if (_commonSettings.UseSystemEmailForContactUsForm)
        {
            from = emailAccount.Email;
            fromName = emailAccount.DisplayName;
            body = string.Format("<strong>From</strong>: {0} - {1}<br /><br />{2}",
                    Server.HtmlEncode(fullName),
                    Server.HtmlEncode(email), body);
        }
        else
        {
            from = email;
            fromName = fullName;
        }
        _queuedEmailService.InsertQueuedEmail(new QueuedEmail()
        {
            From = from,
            FromName = fromName,
            To = emailAccount.Email,
            ToName = emailAccount.DisplayName,
            Priority = 5,
            Subject = subject,
            Body = body,
            CreatedOnUtc = DateTime.UtcNow,
            EmailAccountId = emailAccount.Id
        });

        model.SuccessfullySent = true;
        model.Result = _localizationService.GetResource("ContactUs.YourEnquiryHasBeenSent");

        //activity log
        _customerActivityService.InsertActivity("PublicStore.ContactUs", _localizationService.GetResource("ActivityLog.PublicStore.ContactUs"));

        return View(model);
    }

    model.DisplayCaptcha = _captchaSettings.Enabled && _captchaSettings.ShowOnContactUsPage;
    return View(model);
}
```

Note: ContactUs -method is a default method in NopCommerce, iv'e tried changing a few things but im not getting annywhere. I just need to send the list of products retrieved from the database through "DailyBestsellersReport method" to the email adress of the store owner.

In simple theory I would like to do something like this:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Bestsellers")]
[CaptchaValidator]
public ActionResult SendBestSellersList(BestSellersReportLine model)
{
    DailyBestsellersReport();
}
```

Comment: Iv'e tried filtering ContactUsSend method and getting some errors. This method is actually a formular on the webpage where the customer has to fill his email adress, name and enquiry text message. I only wan't to send the data from my method "MyIListMethod()" to store owners adress.

Comment: Usually a mail contains a body (HTML or text as you want). You would build up a body out of your data. Alternative: Create an excel or whatever and attach it. The current state of the question does not enable us to you you because: there is no clear question (questions like please do/google this, etc. arre unwanted) and no error you can show. Mail sending is hidden behind a service and from what you wrote there are open questions in terms of your requiredment

Comment: @KristofferAndersson your requirement is unclear cant get what u want to do

Comment: I appologize for being unclear. I'll edit the question and try to be more specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although this isn't a direct answer, If you are looking for an easy reusable option I recommend MVC Mailer, It's available as a NuGet Package:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvcMailer

And also there is a nice step by step that anyone can get their head around -

https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/wiki/MvcMailer-Step-by-Step-Guide

Another Tutorial:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek2MvcMailerSendsMailsWithASPNETMVCRazorViewsAndScaffolding.aspx

Comment: Has this helped you - if so, please accept as the answer